# La kvanto da fiŝoj en la maro pli kaj pli "malmultas/malmultiĝas"?

Tags: transitivity

Mi ie legis la frazon "La kvanto da fiŝoj en la maro pli kaj pli malmultas.". La vorto "malmultas" iomete ĝenas min, ĉar "malmultas" signifas "estas malmulte da". Iel mi sentas, ke "malmultiĝas" estus pli taŭge, se antaŭe oni havas "pli kaj pli". Kia estas via opinio?

Answer (score 3):

`malmultiĝas` definitive, pli bone `malgrandiĝas` (ĉar unu kvanto) aŭ `malkreskas`.